# Integration of my own function with wordpress s2members plugin

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I want to know if s2members plugin hooks can help me solve my issue or not. Below is my requirement.

I want to sale for example say ebook. and I want to run some custom function in my plugin when user buy this ebook (or page access). So I think the paypal action hook will help me. I have tried some hooks like

```
add_action("ws_plugin__s2member_after_paypal_return", "my_function");
```

(of course in must used plugin direction with s2-hacks.php file name) but could not make it working.

Can you please suggest me some good filter /action hooks so that i can run my own function when user successfully pays for ebook (even if the user is not redirected back to site from paypal and payment notification is received through IPN ?).

One more question, how these hooks work ? I mean on front end or on backend with IPN response ? I am just asking as I am testing hooks by printing out something but nothing is being printed on frontend page.

Comment: this really depends on what the hook function is designed to do . you will need to read the code carefully for that - and also to verify which hooks are enabled ..